# RSpec - mock a private class method call inside a request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is my class

```
class MyClass

  def run

    to_be_mocked("arg")

    ## etc

  end

  private

  def to_be_mocked(arg)
    # implementation
  end

end
```

and my Controller, which is what I am writing the request specs for, call this class.
This are my request specs:

```
  context "Some context" do
    context "some sub context" do
      before :each do
        allow(MyClass). to receive(: to_be_mocked).with(account.url).and_return(false)
      end
      it "responds with a 200" do
        do_request
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["field"]).to eq true
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
```

However my mocking fails with an `MyClass does not implement: to_be_mocked`

Already tried removing the private keyword, but got the same results.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mocking on the class, which is how you mock you "static" class-level methods. For example, if your method was `def self.foo` and you called it via `MyClass.foo`, then `allow(MyClass)` is the way to go.

Your method is not a class-level method, it's an instance method. You invoke it by first creating an instead of `MyClass` and then calling the method on that instance. You need to use `allow_any_instance_of` to mock the method for all future instances of the class:

```
allow_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(....)
```

Comment: It should be noted though that the documentation discourages the use of `any_instance`. Whatever the real goal is there are better ways such as constructor injection.

Comment: I agree with @max. Create a double and stub the double. You can stub `new` on the class if needed to accomplish this https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/mockprivate#spec.rb